# Prevent Explorer From Expanding Network Folders when in Folders View

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

When you are browsing a network share and there are over 1000 folders in the root (like at work), is there a way to prevent Explorer from expanding all the Folders when you have the "Folders" view enabled?

Explorer will open the folder your double clicked on, and show that in the right navigation pane, and it's great, but wait about five seconds and the rest of the folder list pops into view, I'd rather that not happen.

There is only one folder I'm interested in (or have access to), and it's annoying waiting for Explorer to load the rest of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I just bookmark my folders that I want so that I do not have to go through that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for one folder, note that you can map drive letters to subfolders of a share.

Answer (score 0):

Have you played with the "Simple folder view" setting?  If I understand the problem correctly, it might help to disable it.  In the Windows Explorer menu: Tools > Folder Options > View > Display simple folder view in Explorer's Folders list.  This is one of the settings I disable immediately upon installing Windows XP.  Again, not sure if that's quite what you're asking, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

[This tip](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-network-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/) worked to remove the Network icon from Windows 7 Explorer altogether: